# Cargar Reciclerview con un spinner

Tags: android-studio, recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore, arrayadapter, android-spinner

Tengo un spinner que muestra los materias, al selccionar X item debe mostrarme caracteristicas de este.

Sin embargo no lo hace, hasta que giro la pantalla, se actualiza el RecyclerView, pido apoyo que al seleccionar sea cargado el recyclerview con los valores de X item.

El recyclerview muestra las clases que es un Array dentro de Firestore, lo muestra correctamente, solo que se muestra solo al girar la pantalla.

Pago_listado.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                if(parent.getItemIdAtPosition(position)!=0){
                    String producto=parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                    listDatos=new ArrayList();

```
                SharedPreferences pref_credenciales = getContext().getSharedPreferences("credenciales", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                mFirestore.collection("Productos").whereEqualTo("Titulo",producto).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                                //Mostrar total por cobrar
                                Double Costo= (Double) document.getData().get("Costo");
                                DecimalFormat currency = new DecimalFormat("$###,###.##");
                                Pago_cobrar.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.Pago_totalcobrar) +
                                        " "+currency.format(Costo));
                                //Mostrar las clases
                                if(document.getData().get("Acceso").equals(getContext().getResources().getString(R.string.Precio_AccesoClase))){
                                    ArrayList<String> list = (ArrayList<String>) document.get("Clases");
                                    for (String item : list) {
                                        listDatos.add(item);
                                    }
                                }
                               }
                        }
                    }
                });
                ClasesAdapter adapter = new ClasesAdapter(listDatos);
                recyclerViewArticulos.setAdapter(adapter);

                Pago_cobrar.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.Pago_totalcobrar));
                Pago_cobrar.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
            }else{
                Pago_cobrar.setText(R.string.Pago_basico);
                Pago_cobrar.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

la solucion al error, fue algo que ya sabia mas no recordaba, que la consulta tarda unos milisegundos mas que la computacion del codigo.

Asi que como solucion coloque el adapter si encuentra resultados, no al final como lo tenia.

```
            SharedPreferences pref_credenciales = getContext().getSharedPreferences("credenciales", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            mFirestore.collection("Productos").whereEqualTo("Titulo",producto).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                            //Mostrar total por cobrar
                            Double Costo= (Double) document.getData().get("Costo");
                            DecimalFormat currency = new DecimalFormat("$###,###.##");
                            Pago_cobrar.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.Pago_totalcobrar) +
                                    " "+currency.format(Costo));
                            //Mostrar las clases
                            if(document.getData().get("Acceso").equals(getContext().getResources().getString(R.string.Precio_AccesoClase))){
                                    ArrayList<String> list = (ArrayList<String>) document.get("Clases");
                                    for (String item : list) {
                                        listDatos.add(item);
                                    }

                                }
                                ClasesAdapter adapter = new ClasesAdapter(listDatos);
                                recyclerViewArticulos.setAdapter(adapter);
                               }
                        }
                    }
                });
                Pago_cobrar.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.Pago_totalcobrar));
                Pago_cobrar.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
            }else{
                listDatos.clear();
                ClasesAdapter adapter = new ClasesAdapter(listDatos);
                recyclerViewArticulos.setAdapter(adapter);
                Pago_cobrar.setText(R.string.Pago_basico);
                Pago_cobrar.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            }

        }
```

Comment: Si, después de algunas pruebas, lo logre